# Ignore pristinity of the specific field

Tags: redux-form

I have a form in which fields are setting up in dropdown menu `onChange` handler: `change()` form fields.

Form submit button disabled: `pristine || !valid || submitting`.

I can try to set up value of dropdown menu field in `initialValues` in `onChange`. Is there any other way to ignore field pristinity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can :

> To keep dirty form values when it reinitializes, you can set
>   keepDirtyOnReinitialize to true

from http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/initializeFromState/

so when you are using

```
export default reduxForm({
  // ...
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true
})(MyForm);
```